# Is There Anything Like an ``AddtoIndex'' Command to Add a Statement at the End of the Index

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I would like to add a ``THE END'' to the end of an Index.

Is there a command when creating an Index analogous to the `\addtocontents` command for the TOC?
I am using PDFLATEX.

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Sentence\index{Index Entry1} \newpage
Sentence\index{Index Entry2} \newpage

\idxlayout{columns=2}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index:

[image]

Again, I would like to add ``THE END'', preferably centered, somewhere after the index entries.

Thank you.

Comment: how to be more simple: say simpler instead of more simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put the extra text after `\printindex`. Below I added a bit of vertical space.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Sentence\index{Index Entry1} \newpage
Sentence\index{Index Entry2} \newpage

\idxlayout{columns=2}
\printindex

\vspace{1cm}\centering\large THE END
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That works nicely.  However, would you know if this can be done using some type of index command, which might offer the possibility of adding (positioned) comments/statements  within the Index itself? something analogous to the addtocontents command that Table of Contents has? Thank you again for your useful answer.

Comment: @mlchristians what kind of comment/statement do you want to include? There is the possibility of creating categories that are printed within the index, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593382/categorising-and-aligning-entries-in-index. For random comments you might be able to add an index entry without page number, but that would need some tricks, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/remove-page-number-from-index-entries. But if you want you can open a new question to make your new use case clear.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment.